# IIIS 7 Directory Browsing

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm new to IIS7 so please bear with me.

I'm trying to set up Directory Browsing on a virtual directory. Trouble is, when I go into the option is IIS the options are disabled (i.e. I cannot tick them!).

I've tried going up the folder structure... right to Default Web Site... the option is still disabled.

So, I think I should be doing something at the top level to enable the whole option? But what?

FWIW Within Server Manager --> Web Server (IIS) --> Role Services --> Directory Browsing is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out tucked away on the right hand side there is an "enable" option.

Great UI design!

Thanks for looking anyway!